# Zoom H4n parts?

Tags: zoom, zoom-h4n, replacement-parts

I'm trying to find a UK parts supplier for Zoom H4n parts.

Specifically, I'm looking for a battery cover.

I can't seem to find anyone that doesn't want high delivery charges or isn't charging a bomb for this tiny, flimsy piece of plastic.

Does anyone know where I should be looking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thomann.de have them in their stock. I ordered from their website two years ago.

Comment: Thanks for that. I ran a few searches over there but couldn't find it - do you have a direct link?

Comment: Uhm... Sorry. I searched for my own and recognized, that it's not there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fullcompass.com/product/440854.html?utm_source=googleps&utm_medium=shopping&utm_campaign=googleps&gclid=COXA2pTI5LkCFVGe4Aod_GIAUw

Unfortunately, that's an absurd price, but the aftermarket doesn't look great. Have you contacted samson? Or Zoom?

Comment: That's exactly the part I'm looking for but they don't ship outside the US!  I tried Zoom before and got nowhere. Thanks for the tip on Samson though, I'll try them next.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I broke my battery cover about 1.5 years ago. It doesn't lock, so I just use Scotch Tape to fixate it. :D